# Influence browser download destination

Tags: html, http, download, savefiledialog

is there a way to influence the browsers download directory for a given HTTP download? The scenario is that some of our users are complaining that they have to click through the directory structure whenever they download a file. As I don't know their individual preferences, it would be nice to make the browser use the last chosen download directory. Is this possible? I know that users can choose their download destination from within most browsers' options dialog (firefox, chrome, etc.), but can I influence that behavior from the server side?

Thanks,
Mo

Comment: You definitely cannot do this. No way.

Comment: Your users are complaining about how every HTTP download across the internet works? I'd hate to have your user base hahaha... Instruct them how to set up their preferences in their browser of choice.

Comment: Hmm ... I thought so. Thats precisely what I instructed them to do, but hey .. you never know if there isn't some weird hack to accomplish it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side, no.  Your browser client controls where to download in the Preferences/Options (depending what browser you are using).

However, you can via JavaScript.  Take a look at this control:

- ($$)   http://www.ardentedge.com/pr_fd.htm

or if you are only using IE, you can use this:

```
document.execCommand("saveas",false,"c:\\where\\yo u\\want\\to\\save\\it\\to.txt");
```

Comment: As I understand, this ardent-thing is used for selecting files from the filesystem, which is not precisely my usecase. But thanks for the pointer! If I had credits, I would upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use Content-Disposition to set the filename, as far as I'm aware you can't set the folder as this would be (at least) platform dependent:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using a Flash movie, but without resorting to client plugins (using normal HTTP/HTML) this is not possible (mostly for security reasons).

Users can control this in most browsers using their settings.

Answer (score 0):

'Classic' web content can't access the local file system. Maybe there is some voodo magic hidden inside ActiveX components or Java applets that would be able to do such a thing, but that could  potentially be very complex / restrictive / dangerous.

If there is a routine in which user needs to download which file, you could consider writing a simple HTTP client application that handles the whole process for the user.